# How to execute parallel transactions in Clojure

Tags: clojure, stm

I have a sequence of customers that needs to be processed in parallel. I tried to use a `pmap` for that. The result is painfully slow, much slower than a sequential implementation. The inner function `process-customer` has a transaction. Obviously, the pmap launches all the transactions at once and they end up retrying killing performance. What is thee best way to parallelize this?

```
(defn process-customers [customers]
  (doall 
    (pmap 
      (fn [sub-customers]
        (doseq [customer sub-customers]
          (process-customer customer)))
      (partition-all 10 customers))))
```

**EDIT**:
 The  `process-customer` function involves the below steps. I write the steps for brevity. All the steps are inside a transaction to ensure another parallel transaction does not cause inconsistencies like negative stock.

```
(defn- process-customer [customer]
  "Process `customer`. Consists of three steps:
  1. Finding all stores in which the requested products are still available.
  2. Sorting the found stores to find the cheapest (for the sum of all products).
  3. Buying the products by updating the `stock`.
)
```

**EDIT 2:** The below version of `process-customers`  has the same performance as the parallel `process-customers`  above. The below is obviously sequential.

```
(defn process-customers [customers]
  "Process `customers` one by one. In this code, this happens sequentially."
  (doseq [customer customers]
    (process-customer customer)))
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about what processing entails, what the expected performance characteristics are, etc., I don't know how this could be expected to be answerable. Please try to provide a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code someone else can run to model the problem and test their proposed solutions.

Comment: (A good solution might, f/e, consist of making the transaction's logic commutative; of course, we can't tell if that's feasible unless we can see it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I have an edit. Notice, this is a transaction that looks through a series of stores and gets the cheapest of the stores. If a customer wants to buy from more than one product, he must buy all from the cheapest store. That might be impossible to formulate as commutative. The stock of that store is then decreased. Of course, we do not want negative stock.

Comment: BTW -- what specific operation makes this slow, and thus makes parallelization important? Is there an external (database or other I/O-operation) lookup?

Comment: There is no long-running process. That seems to be the question you are asking :). I am merely logging on the screen. I can also turn off the logging. I was thinking because I am processing many customers parallelization would result in a performance boost. The shared resource `stock` which has to be kept consistent seems to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Have you seen the demo with Conway's Game of Life implemented in Clojure using refs / dosync? I have trouble believing that a well-implemented algorithm with only 10 transactions trying to run concurrently would bog things down when an entire screen of cells can behave properly with each cell acting on its own. (Nobody would *want* to implement it that way, but that was a quite effective demo of how well the whole thing can work together in practice).

Comment: what does your core datastructure look like?

Comment: If all your transactions take roughly the same time, you could easily end up with a lot of collisions in the transaction system. That would lead to a lot of transactions getting restarted and thus to consuming a lot of time. You could try to look into the history of the Refs for debugging. See stress-test code at https://gist.github.com/Chouser/456326 and (old but still valid) discussion starting http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2010-06-28.html#16:02 for some background understanding.

Comment: Also, does the situation improve if you remove the `partition-all`? And my next go-to solution when `pmap` just isn't good enough is usually [reducers](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your transaction is locking on the inventory for the full life cycle of `process-customer`.  This will be slow as all customers are racing for the same universe of stores.  If you can split the process into two phases: 1) quoting and 2) fulfilling and applies transaction only on (2) then the performance should be much better. Or if you buy into `agent` programming, you will have transaction boundary automatically defined for you at the message level.  Here is one sample you can consider:

```clj
(defn get-best-deal
  "Returns the best deal for a given order with given stores (agent)"
  [stores order]
  ;;
  ;; request for quotation from 1000 stores (in parallel)
  ;;
  (doseq [store stores]
    (send store get-quote order))
  ;;
  ;; wait for reply, up to 0.5s
  ;;
  (apply await-for 500 stores)
  ;;
  ;; sort and find the best store
  ;;
  (when-let [best-store (->> stores
                             (filter (fn [store] (get-in @store [:quotes order])))
                             (sort-by (fn [store] (->> (get-in @store [:quotes order])
                                                       vals
                                                       (reduce +))))
                             first)]
    {:best-store best-store
     :invoice-id (do
                   ;; execute the order
                   (send best-store fulfill order)
                   ;; wait for the transaction to complete
                   (await best-store)
                   ;; get an invoice id
                   (get-in @best-store [:invoices order]))}))
```

and to find best deals from 1,000 stores for 100 orders (Total 289 line items) from 100 products:

```clj
(->> orders
       (pmap (partial get-best-deal stores))
       (filter :invoice-id)
       count
       time)
;; => 57
;; "Elapsed time: 312.002328 msecs"
```

*Sample business logic:*

```clj
(defn get-quote
  "issue a quote by checking inventory"
  [store {:keys [order-items] :as order}]
  (if-let [quote (->> order-items
                   (reduce reduce-inventory
                           {:store store
                            :quote nil})
                   :quote)]
    ;; has inventory to generate a quote
    (assoc-in store [:quotes order] quote)
    ;; no inventory
    (update store :quotes dissoc order)))

(defn fulfill
  "fulfill an order if previuosly quoted"
  [store order]
  (if-let [quote (get-in store [:quotes order])]
    ;; check inventory again and generate invoice
    (let [[invoice inventory'] (check-inventory-and-generate-invoice store order)]
      (cond-> store
        invoice (->
                  ;; register invoice
                  (assoc-in [:invoices order] invoice)
                  ;; invalidate the quote
                  (update :quotes dissoc order)
                  ;; update inventory
                  (assoc :inventory inventory'))))
    ;; not quoted before
    store))
```

Comment: The entire "stores" is now an agent. I have two questions. 1. If you then run several threads, will their requests to quote and fulfil not be executed one at a time? 2. If that is the case, is this not the same as sequential implementation?

Comment: From a store perspective, the unit of work is done once a quote is out. Then it can switch to serve another customer/order right away.  Customers can take their time in making their own purchase decisions without blocking any store. This is just reflecting how multi-thread/task works in real life scenario.

Comment: Btw, agent programming is just one way to model the solution. You can achieve similar throughput if appropriate locking granularity is applied with your  approach. Something like Row lock (one store) vs. Table lock (the universe of stores).